# Creatting a variable that stores a light sensor reading one second and after the program initializes. (RobotC Natural Language)

Tags: robotc

The variable needs to store this information for the rest of the program, and remain static so I can create another int that gives the difference between the initial and current readings. Would I use timers for this? None of the RobotC documentation is helpful.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service!   Post what you have tried and how it differs from what you expected  I.E. post a [mcve].  We can help you debug a problem, but we do not write the code for you

Comment: I would suggest using a timer and implement an interrupt for when the timer expires that saves the second input.

Comment: Most of us do not know the 'robotc natural language' so please post a link to a reference/manual for that language.   Also, what is the environment your coding for?